Reorganize or Rebuild Spatial Indexes
Will there ever be a way to exclude or only include spatial indexes from the IndexOptimize tool?

You could always modify the procedure to add that as an argument.  Otherwise, if all of your spatial indexes are named similarly (like they all include the word spatial) then you could probably use the the indexes parameter on the procedure (ALL_INDEXES, -%spatial%)

That is true. Unfortunately they are not named that way. There is a system table (sys.spatial_indexes) that could be leveraged I suppose.

If this is a request for a feature in that tool you should probably post it here https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues - or maybe submit a  PR there with the desired functionality - anyway "will it ever support feature X" is not a suitable question for here. You could ask how to use the tool to achieve "task X" as with the answer received so far

Here is another solution you could leverage then.  Please forgive me on this as I wrote it in a text editor (don't have an instance handy), but this could work for you.
USE MyDBName

DECLARE @IndexList NVARCHAR(MAX)


;WITH CTE_I AS  
    (
    SELECT N'ALL_INDEXES' AS Iname, 1 AS SortOrder
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-' + I.name AS Iname, 2 AS SortOrder 
    FROM sys.spatialindexes AS I
    )
SET @IndexList = STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), I.Iname), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SortOrder, Iname)
FROM CTE_I AS I

USE DatabaseThatHasOlasStuff

EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize
@Databases = 'MyDBName',
@Indexes = @IndexList
@LogToTable = 'Y'


Great idea. I had considered this. However, there are about 975 spatial indexes. The STRING_AGG function has an 8000 character limit. Might have to get a little more creative, eh?

I updated the answer, if you cast to a MAX type, you can get around the string limitation (not sure if Ola's stuff has a limit though....).  You really may just have to customize Ola's procedure, maybe make one version that ignores spatial and another that only does spatial and call as appropriate.

smashing answer, very good

@Darrell please don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer, and give Jonathan a +1 as well, cheers
